# Переход по ссылке, компонент которой берется из поля input

Tags: javascript, html, ссылки

Есть поле для ввода `<input>`, в него вводится некий текст (вида qwe-***, где * - цифры.
Ниже поля есть кнопка "переход №1". При ее нажатии происходит переход на новую страницу по сформированной ссылке вида `www.blablabla.ru/"текст из поля ввода"`, то есть часть ссылки берется из поля ввода. 
Это все я реализовал так:

```js
function update_href(id,value){
    document.getElementById(id).href='www.blablabla.ru/'+value;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
   <br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Введи номер задачи" onchange="update_href('link', this.value );" size=30 style="width: 300px;">
   <br><br>
   <a href="www.blablabla.ru/" id="link">Перейти в терминал</a><br>
</div>
```

Все работает, ок.
Но есть проблема в дальнейших действиях - требуется сделать еще одну кнопку, с аналогичным переходом по другой ссылке, вида `blabla2.ru/***`, но также использующую текст из поля.
как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно так:

```js
function update_href(id, value){
    id.forEach(function(item) {
      let a = document.getElementById(item);
      a.href = a.dataset.link + value;
    });
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
   <br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Введи номер задачи" oninput="update_href(['link','link_2'], this.value );" size=30 style="width: 300px;">
   <br><br>
   <a href="www.blablabla.ru/" data-link="www.blablabla.ru/" id="link">Перейти в терминал</a><br>
   <a href="www.blablabla2.ru/" data-link="www.blablabla2.ru/" id="link_2">Перейти в терминал #2</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. то что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Замени onchange на oninput например. Onchange не срабатывает когда фокус остается в поле ввода

```js
function update_href(id,value){
    document.getElementById(id).href='http://www.blablabla.ru/'+value;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
   <br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Введи номер задачи" oninput="update_href('link', this.value );" size=30 style="width: 300px;">
   <br><br>
   <a href="www.blablabla.ru/" id="link">Перейти в терминал</a><br>
</div>
```